# How To Add An Image To A Tweet With TwitterAPI?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, twitter

I'm struggling to find documentation on how to add an image to a Tweet through Python's [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI). Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far:

```
consumer_key = ' '
consumer_secret = ' '
access_token_key = ' '
access_token_secret = ' '

from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)
file = open('image.jpg', 'rb')
data = file.read()
r = api.request('statuses/update_with_media', {'status':'Your tweet'}, {'media[]':data})
print(r.status_code)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tweet_media.py", line 48, in <module>
r = api.request('statuses/update_with_media', {'status':'Your tweet'}, {'media[]':data})
TypeError: request() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This example will upload a tweet with an embedded image.  You will need to use TwitterAPI 2.1.8.7 or higher.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
file = open('Your_image.png', 'rb')
data = file.read()
r = api.request('statuses/update_with_media', {'status':'Your tweet'}, {'media[]':data})
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: thanks I've updated the question to include your contribution; however, I'm now getting a TypeError: "TypeError: request() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)"

Any idea why?

Comment: It sounds like you are using an old version of TwitterAPI.  Try the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Put a link into the tweet text.
2. Upload the file to Twitter itself using the [`update_with_media`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) API endpoint.